# Split string in numbering

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose i want my text file contains a list of commands:

```
1. eat, food
   7am
2. brush, teeth
   8am
3. crack, eggs
   1pm
```

How can we get:

```
"eat, food\n7am"
"brush, teeth\n8am"
"crack, eggs\n1pm"
```

I'm trying to use the classic `split()` with loops, but so far i haven't figured out how to get rid of the numbers.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Oh well.. i'm no expert on regex, can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: I do not see any effort for resolving this problem on your own, and no, we do not write code for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `regex` and `str.splitlines`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = """1. eat, food
   7am
2. brush, teeth
   8am
3. crack, eggs
   1pm"""
>>> lis = [re.sub(r'^\d+\.\s*', '', x).strip() for x in s.splitlines()]
>>> it = iter(lis)
>>> for x in it:
    print '{!r}'.format(x + '\n' + next(it))


'eat, food\n7am'
'brush, teeth\n8am'
'crack, eggs\n1pm'
```

Comment: Thanks alot, in meantime i found myself a way, just needed the number of commands given.